# White list a program on Azure Database

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I am working on a program that uses Azure for it's database. It works pretty good, except that I have to authorize every IP address that I access it from. So, if I go to a friends house I have to authorize that IP, and if I go to a coffee shop I have to authorize that IP...

I am hoping that there is a way to authorize the connection from the program, whatever IP it is coming from. Or, worse case senario, turn off that security measure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DON'T**.

The idea behind Firewalling your DB is to protect your data from anything that could have the SQL Server credentials should they somehow leak. It's for your own safety.

Instead, try to write a quick Web Service with ASP.Net WS/Jax RS/Rails/... to expose the DB data in a sane, secure and thoughtful manner. It's not hard and there are tons of tutorials and books on the matter out there.

Comment: Right now everything is feeding into datatable structures, which is really useful in regards to querying and filtering data on Azure. It's relatively fast to pull all the data I'll need from Azure and put it into a datatable, and then run all my queries against that.  We also have an Azure website with PHP, and I could write some kind of API, but how easy is it to take the output from an API (JSON or something else?) and put it into a datatable. Would having the website with the capability to pull and output data really be that much more secure than somehow authorizing the program to do it?

Comment: It is way more secure than going around with the password here and there, as you may never know when you are trying to run your program in a keylogged computer. If a WS-consuming app is ran from a keylogged computer the potential damage is contained within that user's domain over the database, instead of potentially the whole schema. With WS users you decide how much you want users to be able to do in code, and partition your data to cater to each user's needs. Not to mention the convenience of enabling diverse kinds of clients to access that data

Answer (score 2):

Although **NOT Recommended**, but if you want to turn off this security measure you can allow connections to your SQL database from all IP Addresses by setting the IP address range to `0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255` in Azure Portal.

Another alternative would be to dynamically manage allowed IP addresses by using Azure Service Management API. You can manage Firewall rules using this API. You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505717.aspx

So what you could do is have a small service running in Azure. When your application starts, it sends the current IP address to your service and your service sets the IP address in the firewall rules. When the application terminates, it sends another request to your service and then your service removes that IP address from the firewall rule.

Comment: I do like your suggestion about using the API to add/remove IP's as needed. Seems like this would be more secure than just putting a lot of IP's in the rule table and leaving them. If they are only in there while the program is running, then that's one less hole to worry about...

Answer (score 2):

As @Machinarius so eloquently said **DON'T**. .NET already has a way of exposing data through OData services. You get SOAP or Json, LINQ queries, caching, security even down to the entity or operation level.

Exposing an EF model as an OData service is *very* easy. You can create an ASP.NET Web API OData endpoint using the "Web API 2 OData Controller with actions, using Entity Framework" template as described in the "[Creating an OData Endpoint](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/creating-an-odata-endpoint)" tutorial.

To call the service from a client, you add a service reference to it and then use the proxy to execute LINQ queries. It could be something as simple as:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:1234/odata/");
var container = new ProductService.Container(uri);
var myProducts=container.Products.Where(....);
```

Check "[Calling an OData Service From a .NET Client](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client)" for a detailed tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you need to access your application from random places, why not have a VM configured in Azure with your application installed. And whenever you need your app, fire up that VM, RDP there and work via RDP. Would not need to update connection and much more secure rather then having to allow random IPs to access your database.

I realise this is not an answer to your question, but other stackoverflowers already provided a significant input on your problem. And I do agree with them all. Do not disable the firewall. It is for your own good!